"Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)" when compiling TVM for RISC-V
I am trying to compile TVM to compile Tensorflow models for a RISC-V architecture.
On a host running Ubuntu 24.04, I run the command sequence specified here: Deploy Models and Integrate TVM - cross-compile for RISC-V
however, when running cmake (with sudo) I get the following error:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:226 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:726 (find_package)

I tried to run sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev as suggested by someone on the Internet but it did not work. Do you have any suggestion to solve this error ?
